# unique_constraint on 2 fields not being recognized

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'am trying to do 2 fields unique constraint in Ecto Postgres. So far I managed to do:

In Migration:

```
create unique_index(:presences, [:event_id, :user_id], name: :special_event_user)
```

Changeset:

```
 def changeset(presence, params \\ :empty) do
    presence
      |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
      |> foreign_key_constraint(:user_id)
      |> foreign_key_constraint(:event_id)
      |> unique_constraint(:event_id, name: :special_event_user)
  end
```

Have also tried:

```
|> unique_constraint(:special_event_user)
```

But I keep getting:

```
If you would like to convert this constraint into an error, please
call unique_constraint/3 in your changeset and define the proper
constraint name. The changeset has not defined any constraint.
```

Which I thought I already did. Any suggestions?

Edit:

Action:

```
def assign(conn, %{"event" => event_id}) do
    case Integer.parse(event_id) do
      {val, _ } ->
          case Repo.one(User.unique_user(User, get_session(conn, :login))) do
            nil -> conn
              |> put_flash(:error, "Błąd bazy danych")
              |> redirect(to: "/event")
            result ->
              presence = %Presence{ user_id: result.id, event_id: val, state: Presence.get_assigned } |> Repo.insert!
              conn
                |> put_flash(:info, "Zostałeś zapisany na wydarzenie")
                |> redirect(to: "/event")
          end
    end
  end
```

Egzample presence from above code when there is no error:

```
%Kpsz.Model.Presence{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded>,
 event: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :event is not loaded>,
 event_id: 1, id: 1, inserted_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2015-12-14T15:45:39Z>,
 state: 1, updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2015-12-14T15:45:39Z>,
 user: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :user is not loaded>, user_id: 1}
```

Edit: Now I'm getting:

```
constraint error when attempting to insert model:

    * unique: special_event_user

If you would like to convert this constraint into an error, please
call unique_constraint/3 in your changeset and define the proper
constraint name. The changeset defined the following constraints:

    * unique: presences_special_event_user_index
    * foreign_key: presences_event_id_fkey
    * foreign_key: presences_user_id_fkey
```

Comment: Your definition seems to match the example in the Ecto documentation. Try to pass the index name directly into the constraint like it was done in this [blog](http://blog.praveenperera.com/using-compound-unique-indexes-to-validate-uniqueness-of-ecto-associations), i.e. `unique_constraint(:special_event_user)`

Comment: Same thing for me...

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using to create the record?

Comment: @Gazler Done. Sorry for delay.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are not going through your changeset function.

```
presence =
  %Presence{ user_id: result.id, event_id: val, state: Presence.get_assigned }
  |> Repo.insert!
```

Should be:

```
presence =
  Presence.changeset(%Presence{}, %{user_id: result.id, event_id: val, state: Presence.get_assigned})
  |> Repo.insert!
```

Comment: Well.. mindless copying is painful sometimes. Thank you very much for your time sir.

Comment: Could take another look at the bottom of main post? I am getting another wierd error. It still tells me that i haven't called that function. But this time it prompts the name of the called functions where one is very similar to one i used.

Comment: If you have a constraint error and use `Repo.insert!` instead of `Repo.insert` then it will raise. Could this be what is happening?

Comment: I'm using Repo.insert, i have deleted the "!" from the copied code.

Comment: Are you using `unique_constraint(:event_id, name: :special_event_user)`?

Comment: Nope. But I have tried it before with same effect. I replaced it with unique_constraint(:special_event_user) which i saw on some blog linked somewhere in main post comments.

Comment: Haito - have you tried it since changing to using the `changeset` function?

Comment: Yes i did. Does it create something permament?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97883/discussion-between-gazler-and-haito).

Comment: Maybe it depends on this: `Presence.changeset(%Presence{)`. You have a parenthesis rather than a curly bracket closing the struct

Comment: My ExMachina strikes again, it inserts without using changesets. This answer helped, thanks.